# Workaround blocked email forwarding to external addresses rule

Tags: android, lotus-notes

Our Domino server at work is set to block rules that forward emails to external accounts.  This is a Good Thing.  However, Traveler on my Android doesn't have a way to duplicate the "Level 1" type email functionality from a Blackberry (where you can set alternate notification methods/ringtones/volumes/etc).  gMail on my Droid does.  I'm looking for a way to automatically forward any emails with "Critical" in the subject line to my gMail account (even if it's just the headers, or even a flag email saying to look at Traveler with none of the original data in it), so that gMail can assign it a label that in turn triggers the alternate notification on my Droid.  This has to work whether Notes is running or not.

Is there a way around this blocked rule?  Or is there another way to accomplish what I'm looking for?

Comment: My team has a PC that's always on, so a last-resort alternative would be to use a script (VBS, PowerShell, or something) to check Domino and fire off an email to my gMail account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make an agent to forward emails, but typically places that remove that rule also disable personal agents.

Comment: Agents are turned on, but I was told that they run client side?  That wouldn't help me unless my laptop were docked in the office.

Comment: Looking further into it, I can't set an agent to run on the server (greyed out), only on the client.

Comment: I tested an Agent with Notes closed and it worked.  (My Notes admin said it wouldn't).  Thanks Zach

Comment: No problem.  You may still want to periodically check your Notes to make sure it's still running. It's not unheard of for Notes admins to disable rules that are running on the server, esp. if they end up using a lot of resources.  I typically ignore personal agents until they get into a loop and start spamming or using resources.